# Kohana 3.3 Routing Issue - .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3

I have the following bootstrap.php routing (its the default):

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

I have the following file structure:

```
application/
  classes/
    Constroller/
      Auth.php
```

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I am on an opensuse 11 Amazon EC2 instance and when I go to `mydomain.com/auth` or `mydomain.com/Auth` I am getting a generic 404 message from Apache. Is there something wrong in my htaccess possibly?

Comment: Are you sure your htaccess file is being read by apache?

Comment: @JonLin Well that is certainly a good point. You are saying I should look at my AllowOverride settings. I'll report back.

Comment: Well, make sure that the htaccess file is readable by apache (e.g. 644 or some similar mode), as well as checking the override settings

Comment: @JonLin Your AllowOverride hint was totally correct. I am idiot/.

Comment: You might want to check out the FallbackResource directive in mod_dir. `FallbackResource /index.php` should be able to replace everything but the dot files, application, modules and system protection on apache 2.2.16 and up. The application, modules and system protection is not needed if you place those outside the webroot, which is recommended.

Comment: @JonLin If you add an answer, I will accept it by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the htaccess file is readable by apache (e.g. 644 or some similar mode) and that the [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) setting in the server/vhost config is set to something appropriate (`All` or `FileInfo`).